# Finding $\int \frac{3^{\tanh(x)}dx}{\cosh^2(x)}$

Tags: calculus, integration

I did:

$$\int \frac{3^{\tanh(x)}dx}{\cosh^2(x)}$$

$u = \tanh(x)$, $du = sech^2(x)$

$$=\int3^u du = 3^{\tanh(x)}*\ln3*sech^2(x)+C$$

Is this correct?

Comment: You can use wolframalpha.com to double-check your result

Comment: Hint:
$$\frac{1}{\sin(x)^2 \cos(x)^2}=\frac{4}{\sin(2x)^2}=4\csc(2x)^2.$$

The integral of $\csc(x)^2$ is $-\cot(x)$.

Comment: What is the connection with the title ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note,

$$\int3^u du = \int \frac{d(3^u)}{\ln3} = \frac{3^u}{\ln3} + C =\frac{3^{\tanh x}}{\ln3} + C $$

Comment: I just noticed I swapped the formula for the integral for the one of the derivative. So it's basically right, I just used the wrong formula for the answer.